# Search multiple colums in model rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a search form where I can search one column in my Recipe model using

```
@countrysearch = Recipe.where(:dish_name => params[:search]).all
```

So when i search for a dish say lasagne I get a result, however i would like to be able to search another 3 columns within the recipe model, country_of_origin, difficulty and preperation_time.

I have tried this

```
@countrysearch = Recipe.where({:dish_name => params[:search], :country_of_origin => params[:search], :difficulty => params[:search], :preperation_time => params[:search]}).all
```

but this does not seem to work either

Can anyone offer a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code uses `AND` but you want `OR` I think:

```
@countrysearch = Recipe.where("dish_name = ? OR country_of_origin = ? OR difficulty = ? OR preperation_time = ?",
    params[:search],
    params[:search],
    params[:search],
    params[:search]
)
```

If you don't want to use an SQL string you can use the `arel_table`:

```
at             = Recipe.arel_table
search         = params[:search]
@countrysearch = Recipe.where(at[:dish_name].eq(search).or(at[:country_of_origin].eq(search)).or(at[:difficulty].eq(search)).or(at[:preperation_time].eq(search)))
```

But for the current version of Rails I would prefere the first method because this is better readable. In Rails 5 you will have better methods for this sort of queries. (I will update this post if this becomes available.)

Comment: ah so it does, obvious now you pointed it out. thanks very much, getting results back now :)

Comment: If you wanto to search for a lot of items in a big database you maybe should think about using http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx or some other search engine.

Comment: yeah this may be something i do if the app gets bigger but for now it is relatively small so keeping it simpler for now, thanks for the suggestion though